# Calculate complexity of recursion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

```
func3(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
        System.out.println("*");
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        System.out.println("*");
        return;
    }
    if(n % 2 != 0) //check if odd
        func3(n - 1)
    func3(n / 2);
    return;
}
```

I need to calculate the complexity of this algorithm, how can i do it when i have for in my code and 2 calls to func3?

Comment: Show your own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

The bit pattern of `n` is very helpful in illustrating this problem.

---

Integer division of `n` by 2 is equivalent to *right-shifting* the bit pattern by one place, discarding the least significant big (LSB). e.g.:

```
                          binary
                       ----------------------
n = 15                 |  0000 1111 
n / 2 = 7 (round down) |  0000 0111 (1) <- discard
```

- An odd number's LSB is always 1.
- An power-of-two only has 1 bit set.

---

Therefore:

- The best case is when `n` is a power-of-2, i.e. `func3(n - 1)` is only called *once* at the end when `n = 1`. In this case the time complexity is:

  > ```
  > T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n)
  > ```
- What is the worst case, when `func3(n - 1)` is *always* called once in each call to `func3`? The result of `n / 2` must always be odd, hence:

  **All significant bits of `n` must be 1.**

  This corresponds to `n` equal to a power-of-two *minus one*, e.g. `3, 7, 15, 31, 63, ...`

  In this case, the call to `func3(n - 1)` will *not* yield another call to the same function, since if `n` is odd then `n - 1` must be even. Also, `n / 2 = (n - 1) / 2` (for integer division). Therefore the recurrence relation is:

  > ```
  > T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n log n)
  > ```

One can obtain these results via the *Master theorem*.

Comment: thank you for your great explanation, I just cant understand where the 2*T(n/2) came from. especially the 2

Comment: @DavidZaltsman One of the `T(n/2)` comes from the recursive call `f(n/2)` on the penultimate line. Note that because `n` is odd, there is also a recursive call `f(n-1)`, from the line just before. From there will be a call to `f((n-1)/2)`, and as explained by meowgoesthedog (nice explanation btw) `n` is odd, `n/2 = (n-1)/2`; hence you have two calls to `f(n/2)` overall. Note that when you are in the recursive call `f(n-1)`, `n-1` is even so `f(n-2)` won't be called.

Comment: First of all , the explanation was great! Second I have a question about the complexity. I can understand where the 2*T(n/2)+o(n) comes from but I can’t understand why the recursive call f(n-1) has no impact of the complexity.. it’s like all that matters is how many times one calls the f(n/2) . Each time the func is being called , there is o(n) “work” so why f(n-1) is nothing? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @davidzaltsman It doesn't have "no impact" - it is what produces the "2" in 2T(n/2). Please read the post carefully and it will become apparent.